# In LibreOffice Calc, why would sort buttons and menu items suddenly become disabled?

Tags: libreoffice, sorting, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, toolbar

I was creating a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc.  Several times, I used the "Sort Ascending" and "Sort Descending" toolbar buttons.  All was well, and everything was working as expected.

As I continued to edit my spreadsheet, I noticed that all the "Sort" toolbar buttons were dimmed, and so were the corresponding menuitems.

Why would all the sort functions suddenly become disabled in LibreOffice Calc?  All other functionality appears to be working as expected.

If it matters, I'm currently using LibreOffice Calc v7.1.2.2.  I did try closing LibreOffice Calc and restarting it, as well as rebooting the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you enabled tracking changes by mistakes by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. When it is done, there are not popup to alert that it is enabled. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then Yes to stop recording the changes. You will be able to again sort.

Comment: Thanks Reddy!  Upvoted!  I bet this is it.  I have an tool that uses Ctrl+Shift+C, and so I very well might have pressed that key combination.  I can't believe (well, I can!), that LO doesn't have any indication that the user enabled tracking changes.  Very poor UX/UI design for sure.  I'm not a device that has LO right now, but I'll check this out first thing when I am.  I'm almost sure you guessed right, and I'm equally sure that without your answer, it would have taken me much, much more time to figure it out.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Reddy, you nailed it on the head.  I did exactly as you recommended, and it worked perfectly.  Thank you.  When I pressed Ctrl+Shift+C to end tracking changes, did all the "tracking" get removed, or is it still stored in the file (or elsewhere)?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Good that it works! It seems that tracking changes stops when when you terminate tracking. I presume the changes are saved in the file itself and are deleted when you stop tracking them.

Comment: Thank you Reddy!